# How to apply a negative keyword list to a GAM order

Tags: google-ad-manager

I am setting up a basic order in Google Ad Manager- it is for a pharma company and they have an extensive list of negative keywords and prohibit their ads being served on pages where those keywords exist. I would like to apply these keywords to their order, and I found some info on "labels," which I set up, but I am unsure how to apply those to the order to indicate the negative context, or if this is even the correct method to do so!

I found some info on "labels," which I set up, but I am unsure how to apply those to the order to indicate the negative context.

Comment: Did you happen to find out a way to do this, or is this impossible in GAM and is only doable in MCC / Google Ads?

Comment: I did not! We went another direction with the client, as this didn't seem to be possible!

Comment: Thanks for the reply - we looked around as well on how to do this but doesn't seem like it's plausible to do in GAM without some complex targeting via tags that will take heaps of man hours. 

Curious on the direction you ended up taking to solve this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible in GAM. It is achievable via KV pair(s) but you need to properly tag your pages.